# Unicode points for Arabic dotless letters

Tags: arabic, unicode

I am looking for a Unicode equivalent of an Arabic word featuring dotless letters FEH and NOON:

[image]

This is to mimic a handwriting style that doesn't use dots.

I've found:

[ARABIC LETTER DOTLESS FEH (U+06A1)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06a1/index.htm)

but I can't find non-isolated (contextual) versions of it.

E.g. the normal (dotted) FEH has these five contextual forms:

[image]

I'm looking for the same but without the dot. Do they exist?

Comment: You should sign up to [the Semitic Languages site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113173/semitic-languages?referrer=yRzQoZHRmyFp7Xtv9TLV8g2) and the [Arabic language site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105382/arabic-language?referrer=yRzQoZHRmyGkLP2Gbw0DUw2).

Comment: @jknappen Indeed. A [new proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages?referrer=yRzQoZHRmyHgtLwleeZrnA2) has been started, though I'm pessimistic about its chances to succeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By policy, UNICODE does not assign code points for contextual variants. Some contextual variants are in by exception—their purpose is to guarantee round-trip equivalence with some older legacy standards that were in existence before UNICODE. So you should go with the single code point for ARABIC LETTER DOTLESS FEH (U+06A1) and let the typesetting engine do the contextualisation. When the engine does not reproduce the handwriting faithfully, you can hint the contextual variant using one of the two characters ZERO WIDTH JOINER and ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER.

EDIT: This means in particular, that you should not use the available contextual variants for encoding the Arabic script and treat them as deprecated or compatibility only characters.